# Pull the data from a set of chosen rows of a table

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have the matrix shown. Suppose I want the entire row data associated with specified column IDs 106, 110, 109. The output would be {106, Job2, J2},{110, Job7, J7},{109, Job5, J5}.

```
m = {{102, Job1, J1}, {106, Job2, J2}, {109, Job5, J5}, {110, Job7, 
   J7}, {120, Job9, J9}, {125, Job15, J15}}
MatrixForm[m]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Construct an [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) with the first column as keys using [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html):

```
assoc =  GroupBy[m, First, First]
```

> <|102 -> {102, Job1, J1}, 106 -> {106, Job2, J2}, 
>    109 -> {109, Job5, J5}, 110 -> {110, Job7, J7}, 
>    120 -> {120, Job9, J9}, 125 -> {125, Job15, J15}|>

You can extract the columns by mapping `assoc`

```
assoc /@ {106, 109, 110}
```

> {{106, Job2, J2}, {109, Job5, J5}, {110, Job7, J7}}

or using [`Lookup`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html):

```
Lookup[{106, 109, 110}] @ assoc
```

> {{106, Job2, J2}, {109, Job5, J5}, {110, Job7, J7}}

Comment: very slick! ... thank you very much ... kglr

Answer (score 3):

```
index = Association[(#[[2]] -> #[[1]]) & /@ Table[{i, m[[i, 1]]}, {i, 1, Length[m]}]];
m[[index /@ {106, 110, 109}]]
```

> {{106, Job2, J2}, {110, Job7, J7}, {109, Job5, J5}}

The strategy here is to use `Association` to make an index of the first column to the position of each ID in `m`. Then the association (`index`) can be used to extract the positions of arbitrary column IDs, which can be in turn used to extract the row information. This methodology retains the ordering of the query.

Otherwise, if ordering isn't important, `Cases` might be more useful for repeated evaluation:

```
Cases[m, {106 | 110 | 109, __}]
```

> {{106, Job2, J2}, {109, Job5, J5}, {110, Job7, J7}}

`Cases` will also automatically de-duplicate repeated IDs, so keep that in mind if you go that route.

Comment: eyorble: very clever; wonderful and many thanks for your help! ... prg

Comment: This preserves duplicates and ordering `m // Select[MemberQ[{106, 110, 109}, First[#]] &]`

Answer (score 1):

`Lookup` also works with `List`s of `Rule`s:

```
look = MapApply[# -> {##} &] @ m;
```

{102 -> {102, Job1, J1}, 106 -> {106, Job2, J2},
109 -> {109, Job5, J5}, 110 -> {110, Job7, J7},
120 -> {120, Job9, J9}, 125 -> {125, Job15, J15}}

```
Lookup[{106, 109, 110}] @ look
```

{{106, Job2, J2}, {109, Job5, J5}, {110, Job7, J7}}

To omit the `Key`s:

```
look = MapApply[#1 -> {##2} &] @ m;

Lookup[110] @ look
```

{Job7, J7}

Answer (score 1):

Construct an association using `Association` as follows:

```
assoc = Merge[Association[# -> {##}] & @@@ m, Catenate]
```

You can extract the columns using `Extract`:

```
Values@Extract[assoc, List /@ {Key /@ {106, 109, 110}}][[1]]

(*{{106, Job2, J2}, {109, Job5, J5}, {110, Job7, J7}}*)
```